# wolframscript under Linux, version 11

Tags: front-end, scripting

I just installed v11, and I wanted to try `wolframscript` at the console.

Whatever I try, it works, but always adding at the beginning the annoying warning

```
FrontEndObject::notavail: 
   A front end is not available; certain operations require a front end.
```

which it adds even for a simple `wolframscript -code 2+2`

There is a way to avoid it?

Comment: Are you running it on a headless machine?

Comment: no, it's a desktop - but I like to use the console whenever I can

Comment: So just to make it clear, you do have an X server running, right?

Comment: :-) yes, I have it - and the M frontend works perfectly on it... (it is a Fedora fc20)

Comment: I don't have M11 on Linux now to confirm, but it sounds like something worth reporting to Wolfram Support.

Comment: will do it - thank you

Comment: I am on Fedora 24 and I can run all examples in the docs without errors.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Wolfram was that they were unable to replicate my bug - but they just tried it with Ubuntu. From what I see by *b.gatessucks*, whatever issue it is, it must be present at least in Fedora fc20...

Anyway - just to show myself that I could do it, and just for fun - I put this code in my .bashrc (it needs *ImageMagick*):

```
wcalc(){
        echo -n -e "Input/Output loop with Mathematica syntax\npre-pend \"g\" to have graphics output (if ImageMagick installed)\nCtrl-C to exit\nw> "
        perl -wne'chomp;(substr($_, 0, 1) eq "g") ?
        do{$x="g";$_=~s/^.//;$a=`wolframscript -code "$_"  -format PNG >file.png 2>/dev/null`}:
        do{$x="";$a=`wolframscript -code $_ 2>&1`};
        $x eq "" ? do{@b=split(/\n/,$a);print"$b[2]\nw> "}:
        do{print"\nw> ";system("display file.png 2>/dev/null&")}';
        }
export -f wcalc
```

With it, the command **wcalc** starts a quick Mathematica session at the console. The same as calling **math** at the console, but with the added benefits that

1) I was able to use wolframscript as I wanted (I get rid of the warning I asked about, by splitting @b and printing just $b[2]), and

2) if you pre-prend your command by "g", e.g.

*w> gPlot[Sin[x],{x,0.,5}]*

it is able to open the graphics (using *display* by *ImageMagick*) .